# Auto Load Error during installing Magento

Tags: autoloader

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\vendor\composer/../phpstan/phpstan/bootstrap.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\vendor/magento/zendframework1/library;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 73

Can some body help ?, i am rele shitting over installing magento.

Comment: please share more information so I help you. Like how to install magento and which version installation command etc..

Comment: Have you granted proper folder permissions? How have you installed Magento? Which Magento version?

Comment: i did every thing which i had to, like the process discribed on the Magento web site its not working out, may be i am missing something --

Comment: I would advise using Docker or VirtualBox for Magento installation. Magento does not support Windows